# String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated. c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to add email to table but it is throwing error the value in email is "prashhanth@oberonit.com". I don't see any anything wrong in the email.I added other emails added fine not this one.

Column RemovedEmail is varchar(50), null

> "String or binary data would be truncated.
> The statement has been terminated."

```
 var constultantUser = intensifyDb.ConsultantUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == email);

  // Delete the item 
  if (constultantUser != null)
  {
     intensifyDb.DeleteObject(constultantUser);// Save changes 
     intensifyDb.SaveChanges();
   }

   if (!intensifyDb.RemovedEmails.Any(x => x.RemovedEmails == email))
   {
      RemovedEmail consultant = new RemovedEmail
      {
          RemovedEmails = email
      };
      intensifyDb.AddToRemovedEmails(consultant);
      intensifyDb.SaveChanges(); // Exception throwing here.
   }
```

### update

As @Bradley request

[image]

Full Code

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmails.Text))
    {
       string txt = txtEmails.Text;
       string[] lst = txt.Split(new Char[] { '\n', '\r' },      
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
       string email = string.Empty;
       var removedEmail = string.Empty;
       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
           var foundEmail = string.Empty;
           foreach (string emailStr in lst)
           {
            email = LastCharFromEmailAddress(emailStr).Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
            var intensifyDb = new IntensifyEntities();

            var constultantUser = intensifyDb.ConsultantUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == email);

            // Delete the item 
            if (constultantUser != null)
            {
               intensifyDb.DeleteObject(constultantUser);// Save changes 
               intensifyDb.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (!intensifyDb.RemovedEmails.Any(x => x.RemovedEmails == email))
            {
               RemovedEmail consultant = new RemovedEmail
               {
                  RemovedEmails = email
               };
               intensifyDb.AddToRemovedEmails(consultant);
               intensifyDb.SaveChanges();
             }
         }
    connection.Close();

    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you please show us  what is doing `AddToRemovedEmails`

Comment: it's there at the bottom of the question.`varchar(50)`

Comment: Based on the error, we know that you are trying to insert or update a value in a column but the value you are trying to insert/update is longer than the max length (in bytes) of the field. If your charset is UTF or some other double-width set, that means that the max string length of a varchar(50) field is actually 25. Please share some more code, e.g. table schema and the body of AddToRemovedEmails, and we may be able to help you.

Comment: Just run the profiler or enable query tracing `intensifyDb.Database.Log = message => Trace.Write(message);`  just before your AddToRemoveEmails method. See what's there in email field.

Comment: Saying UTF is double-width is very misleading. Anyway the datatype is varchar not nvarchar

Comment: @Crowcoder Ok, it is somewhat misleading I suppose, for the 128 out of 1,112,064 code points that are only 1 byte in the character set. And the fact that it's varchar and not nvarchar is exactly the reason why I said if you have a UTF encoded string of length N and you insert it into a varchar(n) field, chances are good that it will overflow because N characters in UTF does not necessarily mean N bytes, whereas n is always the maximum number of bytes the field can hold.

Comment: Now My question is when I am sending prashhanth@oberonit.com which is lessthan 50 characters but code show length 67. How can avoid extra charcters and trip did not work.

Comment: What does the method `LastCharFromEmailAddress` look like? That is what is setting the value of the `email` variable.

Comment: I made edit to my answer please send a hex value back to us this will help to identify extra chars that could look like spaces but they not

Comment: @James123 I updated my post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This exception is usually means that your db field doesn't have enough length

I recommend to go over this code in debugger and check what is the length of the string actually is.

EDIT:

I think its extra spaces copy sting to the editor and check and try to use .Trim()

```
email = email.Trim();
```

If trim doesn't work it could be some Unicode chars that invisible

Try to add this in code:

```
var debugCheck = string.Join("", 
            email.Select(c=> String.Format("{0:X2}", Convert.ToInt32(c))))
```

and send value of debugCheck back to me so I can check it.

(this convert email value to the hex string it will help to identify extra chars that could look like spaces but they not)

*UPDATE:*
So you have this string actually (in hex) `707261736868616E7468406F6265726F6E69742E636F6D200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B2‌​00B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B20‌​0B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B`
200B means Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B) you can remove it by using

```
.Replace("\u200B", "");
```

more generic code to remove all unicode whitespace chars:

```
Regex.Replace(email, @"^[\s,]+|[\s,]+$", "")
```

Comment: "prashhanth@oberonit.com" is less than 50 characters. Unless there is another field that we can't see that is overflowing, something else is wrong.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes, either you are not sending "prashhanth@oberonit.com" like you think you are or the column is not actually 50 wide like you think it is.

Comment: I'm not the OP, so technically I'm not doing anything.

Comment: Alexander V. is correct. The error that you're citing only happens when the data you're inserting/updating into a field exceeds the capacity.

Comment: @VinceHorst There is a gap that exists between being correct and actually providing a helpful answer to OP's question.

Comment: @AlexanderV. length says  `email.Length 67 int` . But how?

Comment: I think its extra spaces copy sting to the editor and check

Comment: Trim didn't work. is there any remove extra characters

Comment: I made some edits to the post in case when trim doesn't work

Comment: @AlexanderV `707261736868616E7468406F6265726F6E69742E636F6D200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B200B`

Comment: @James123 you have a lot of this chars: (200B - U+200B Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' ) at the and of the string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106655/discussion-between-james123-and-alexander-v).